# Error Compiling First OpenGL Redbook Program (triangles.cpp) error: ‘PFNGLDRAWARRAYSPROC’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘PFNGLDRAWARRAYSEXTPROC

Tags: c++, opengl

I've begun learning OpenGL and I'm reading the OpenGL Programming Guide, this is the first piece of example code in the book.

```cpp
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  triangles.cpp
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "vgl.h"
#include "LoadShaders.h"

enum VAO_IDs { Triangles, NumVAOs };
enum Buffer_IDs { ArrayBuffer, NumBuffers };
enum Attrib_IDs { vPosition = 0 };

GLuint  VAOs[NumVAOs];
GLuint  Buffers[NumBuffers];

const GLuint  NumVertices = 6;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// init
//

void
init(void)
{
    static const GLfloat vertices[NumVertices][2] =
            {
                    { -0.90, -0.90 },  // Triangle 1
                    {  0.85, -0.90 },
                    { -0.90,  0.85 },
                    {  0.90, -0.85 },  // Triangle 2
                    {  0.90,  0.90 },
                    { -0.85,  0.90 }
            };

    glCreateBuffers(NumBuffers, Buffers);
    glNamedBufferStorage(Buffers[ArrayBuffer], sizeof(vertices),
                         vertices, 0);

    ShaderInfo  shaders[] = {
            { GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "triangles.vert" },
            { GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "triangles.frag" },
            { GL_NONE, NULL }
    };

    GLuint program = LoadShaders(shaders);
    glUseProgram(program);

    glGenVertexArrays(NumVAOs, VAOs);
    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[Triangles]);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Buffers[ArrayBuffer]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT,
                          GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// display
//

void
display(void)
{
    static const float black[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, black);

    glBindVertexArray(VAOs[Triangles]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// main
//

int

main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glfwInit();

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Triangles", NULL,
                                          NULL);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    gl3wInit();

    init();

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        display();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);

    glfwTerminate();
}
```

I'm getting this error when I try to run it: https://pastebin.com/0qrukUfZ.
I tried installing glew and adding '#include ' near the top of my main.cpp file that but that just changes the error to this: https://pastebin.com/jttwrj0f, I've also tried using freeglut but that does nothing.

I've made sure I've properly installed "vgl.h" and "LoadShaders.h" to the right directories. I'm on Linux if that helps.

Comment: The book is just one reference. Check online sources for the latest spec. OpenGL has gone through a number of iterations and your book may either be too new for the version you're linking against, or too old for the version you're actually using.

Comment: [Edit] the question to include the errors _as text_, not images.  See [ask].

Comment: The book is for OpenGL 4.5 and I've checked to make sure everything I'm linking against is for OpenGL 4.5, the links are also to pastebin, containing the text of the error and no images.